# Could not resolve com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:28.0.0

Tags: java, android

i had this problem when i tried to use gridLayout in android studio.

Here's the code i use to import dependency:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:28.0.0'
```

And here's a full code i use:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.company.exampleapp.chargingreminder"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:28.0.0'
}
```

here's the root-level build.gradle:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and here's the error i get:

```
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:28.0.0.
```

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Show your root-level build.gradle.

Comment: hi @TheWanderer, i've updated my post. i've added root-level build.gradle. What do you think made my code didn't work?

Comment: Please follow https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup#download